# SQL select medications only during covid infection

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables. 
The table 'lab_obs' records results when a patient was tested for covid. 
The table 'medications' has records of all medications taken by all patients (whether tested or not). 
Here is the simplified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE lab_obs (ob_day DATE, 
                          ob VARCHAR(20),
                          patient_id VARCHAR(20)
                         );

CREATE TABLE medications (given_day DATE, 
                          med VARCHAR(20),
                          patient_id VARCHAR(20)
                         );                         

INSERT INTO lab_obs VALUES ('2020-03-01', 'positive', 'p11');
INSERT INTO lab_obs VALUES ('2020-05-01', 'negative', 'p11');
INSERT INTO lab_obs VALUES ('2020-03-02', 'negative', 'p12');
INSERT INTO lab_obs VALUES ('2020-06-01', 'negative', 'p11');
INSERT INTO lab_obs VALUES ('2020-06-01', 'negative', 'p12');

INSERT INTO medications VALUES ('2020-03-05', 'covid_med_11', 'p11');
INSERT INTO medications VALUES ('2020-03-05', 'non_covid_med_12', 'p12');
INSERT INTO medications VALUES ('2020-02-05', 'non_covid_med_11', 'p11');
INSERT INTO medications VALUES ('2020-04-05', 'non_covid_med_41', 'p41');
```

I want to write a SQL that will give me (patient_id, med) 
for patients who tested positive and subsequently tested negative
and all the meds taken during the time between the positive-test and the subsequent negative-test. Basically the query should give me all the meds taken by patients who recovered from Covid !!

Comment: What does `medications` have to do with this question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe he wants the medication name that was given to the patient to be selected too.

Comment: I have edited the question...hopefully it is clear now ?

Comment: Also tag your database

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: postgresql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Not sure if the data structure is yours, but have you considered using a `boolean`/`bit` for the test results for example?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I accepted the answer below  (ref. https://github.com/assamese/spark-python-hl7/blob/54dfb7ff361c2db9cb640e496869222d156c7776/spark_joint_pipeline_step3.py#L36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you could use. Using the lag function to check previous record. I ran it in SQL server. Also, please use codes for observation as the spelling can cause issues e.g postive instead of positive.

```
SELECT m.patient_id, m.med , m.given_day
FROM medications m
JOIN (SELECT patient_id, 
       CASE WHEN ob = 'negative'
             AND lag(ob) OVER (partition by patient_id order by l.ob_day) = 'postive'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END as qualify
      FROM lab_obs l) l ON l.patient_id = m.patient_id AND l.qualify = 1
```

Comment: This works with SparkSQL (ref. https://github.com/assamese/spark-python-hl7/blob/54dfb7ff361c2db9cb640e496869222d156c7776/spark_joint_pipeline_step3.py#L36)

Answer (score 1):

Tried with PostgreSQL (not sure which RDBMS you're using). You'd need window functions and CTEs for this:

```sql
WITH lagged_obs AS (
    SELECT patient_id,
           ob_day,
           ob,
           LAG(ob) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY ob_day) AS lagged_ob
    FROM lab_obs
)
, patient_status_change AS (
    -- Look for status changes, useful for consecutive tests with same result
    SELECT patient_id,
           ob_day AS ob_change_day,
           ob
    FROM lagged_obs
    WHERE ob IS DISTINCT FROM lagged_ob
)
, patient_infected_periods AS (
    -- Build time periods
    SELECT patient_id,
           ob_change_day AS start_date,
           LEAD(ob_change_day)
               OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY ob_change_day) AS end_date,
           ob AS period_status
    FROM patient_status_change
)
SELECT pip.patient_id, m.given_day, m.med
FROM patient_infected_periods pip
    INNER JOIN medications m
    ON pip.patient_id=m.patient_id AND pip.start_date <= m.given_day AND m.given_day < pip.end_date
WHERE pip.period_status='postive'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky.  If someone only tests positive once, then:

```
select m.*
from medications m
where m.given_day >= (select min(l.ob_day)
                      from lab_obs l
                      where l.patient_id = m.patient_id and l.ob = 'positive'
                     ) and
      m.given_day < (select min(l.ob_day)
                     from (select l.*, min(case when ob = 'positive' then ob_day end) as pos_ob_day
                           from lab_obs l
                          ) l
                     where l.patient_id = m.patient_id and
                           l.ob = 'negative' and
                           l.ob_date > pos_ob_day
                        );
```

This works for negative-positive-negative and positive-negative scenarios.

If someone can switch back and forth, then I would suggest using `lag()` like this:

```
select m.*, l.*
from medications m join
     (select l.*,
             lead(ob_day) over (partition by patient_id order by ob_day) as next_ob_day
      from (select l.*,
                   lag(ob) over (partition by patient_id order by ob_day) as prev_ob
           from lab_obs l
          ) l
      where prev_ob is null or prev_ob <> ob
     ) l
     on m.patient_id = l.patient_id and
        m.given_date >= l.ob_day and
        m.given_date < l.next_ob_day and
        l.ob = 'positive';
```

The `l` subquery is determining when someone first tests positive and then the next test date with a different test value.

Comment: @Bruno GordonLinoff VarunT Initially, I will test the query in Postgres, but eventually, I will be using the query in SparkSQL, so not sure which 1 will actually work....Let me try all the suggested queries and then I will accept the 1 that works in SparkSQL

Comment: Unfortunately SparkSQL does not allow "any clause" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690999/spark-sql-with-any-clause)

Comment: @SanjayDas . . . Interesting.  That is so standard, I didn't even think about it.  I modified the answer.